# Add CSS to pages through a CSS file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if it was possible to add CSS to pages through a CSS file, similarly to adding JS to pages through a JS file (contentscript). So, I could just define what pages said CSS file would work on and then it would take effect just like a contentscript. I understand that it is possible to add CSS through a JavaScript file, but it would be more convenient to do it this way instead if possible. If it's not possible, then of course I must use contentscript, but I would first like to know before I rule out any possibilities. I've searched and received no answers - either I'm searching wrong or it really isn't possible. Chrome extensions have come a long way, though, so I'm still not ruling it out until someone who knows can tell me yes & how or no. Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your manifest file must contain a `content script` pointing to a `CSS file`, that will load when a url `matches` your selected url fields...

```
"content_scripts": [ {
   "css": [ "scrollbars.css" ],
   "matches": [ "http://www.google.com/*" ]
} ],
```

This is the same method you would use to inject `javascript code`, except you would point to a `js file` instead...

[More information here...](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Comment: Does this still work in recent Chrome? I feel a regression bug was introduced that breaks CSS insertion through content script.

Comment: Definitely still works... https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score 10):

manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
      "css/style.css"
],
```

content-script.js:

```
var a = chrome.extension.getURL("css/style.css");
$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + a + '" >').appendTo("head");
```

My extension using jQuery

Answer (score 7):

similarly like we add JavaScript in `content_scripts` also add CSS

### Method-1

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["css/style.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js","content.js","my.min.js"]
}],
```

add one more thing on `web_accessible_resources`

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "css/style.css"
  ]
```

if you used any external JavaScript then also add URL in permission tab.

```
"permissions": ["tabs", <all_urls>","http://*/","http://example.com/"]
```

### Method-2

also same this thing using vai programming injection and [insertCSS()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-insertCSS).

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(integer tabId, object details, function callback)
```

**NOTE :**  `web_accessible_resources` add `.css` is not mandatory but as of chrome extension forum is good practice.

Comment: Requires editing to be useful. Remark about `web_accessible_resources` is confusing (and not needed for CSS included as above). Remark about external JS is completely out of place and also not always true. Now, mention of method #2 is actually very useful as it wasn't mentioned here before. I would recommend changing the code from signature to a minimal sample.

Comment: @Xan add `web_accessible_resources` to specify css is not mandatory that not mean you downvote for that and also you can edit that :) and make more useful to other.