# Including CSS with Chrome Extension? (Programmatic Injection Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Looking to squeeze in the CSS for Bootstrap's Popover somewhere in my Chrome Extension. That's literally all I need to do. Include the CSS for a library so my popover (tooltip) is styled.

**So far I've tried** InsertCSS() in the background page, and adding a stylesheet element appended to the head which kept throwing an error requiring it to be listed on "web_accessible_resources" which it was. Spelling was all correct too.

My code:
**NOTE** The content_script file is included for posterity. I don't think it's valuable here, but ymmv. Way too long, but It's there. Yes there is a frame on the page I'm editing.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "RMP",
  "description": "Work in Progress",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.8",
  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","bootstrap.min.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click me!"
  }

}
```

background.js which included a commented out attempt.

```
// On Extension Icon click, inject script
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"}, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bootstrap.min.js"}, function() {
            //chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "bootstrap.min.css", allFrames: "true"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
            });
        });
});
```

And my Content_Script file (reduced code not needed for question. Can post on request or on old posts of mine.)

```
    // Handle page's frame (to allow DOM access)
    var page = top.frames["TargetContent"].document;

    **STUFF HAPPENS HERE.................**  

function addPopover(profPage,profElement) {

    // Retrieve & Format Professor Data
    var name = profElement.textContent;
    var quality = profPage.getElementsByClassName('grade')[0].textContent;    
    var difficulty = profPage.getElementsByClassName('grade')[2].textContent;
    var ratings = profPage.getElementsByClassName('table-toggle rating-count active')[0].textContent;
    ratings = ratings.trim();

    // Concatenate into 1 string
    var content = "Overall Quality: " + quality + "<br />" + "Difficulty: " + difficulty + "<br />" + ratings;

    // Set attributes for popover
    profElement.setAttribute("data-toggle","popover");
    profElement.setAttribute("data-trigger","hover");
    profElement.setAttribute("title",name);
    profElement.setAttribute("data-content",content);
    profElement.setAttribute("data-html",true);


    $(profElement).popover();


}
```

Comment: I think this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452957/add-css-to-pages-through-a-css-file

Comment: @PerunSS Hmm, it could but it'd mean a lot of extra CSS injection. Ideally when my content_script.js file runs through the programmatic injection, I can get the CSS I need for that JS file on the web page somehow. I'm not too familiar with chrome extension architecture, so if I don't even need to inject the CSS that'd be great. I think I do though. I might try that method if I have to, but that's ideally a last ditch effort for me. :(